# "The accomplishments we achieve will allow us to grow as individuals." Is this correct?

Tags: verbs, nouns, collocation

I do not think the verb "achieve" collocates with "accomplishment" as it seems redundant. Any alternative verb suggestion would be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is redundancy there - you can see it easily if you substitute "achievements" for "accomplishments":

> The **achievements** we **achieve** will allow us to grow as individuals.

So you could simplify it to

> Our accomplishments will allow us to grow as individuals.

or

> Our achievements will allow us to grow as individuals.

Comment: +1 Or *We achieve and we grow.*